# Nikon D7100 fEE Error code with Nikon 300mm F4

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7100

Im experiencing a flashing fEE error code with my Nikon D7100 cam when attached to my Nikon 300 mm f4 lens. Ive watched the fix it videos ( manual ring to F32 and lock) on youtube and its not working.All parts and pieces on the cam and lens are intact.

Funny thing is the lens is working on my d750 and my 70/200 is working on the d7100 camera.

Any suggestions or help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Travis

Comment: Have you tried setting the aperture to its smallest setting?